# How to define a function in Laravel 5.5 before the app starts

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

In Laravel 5.5, the `bootstrap/autoload.php` file has been removed. This is where I would have defined a function that *overwrites* the typical Laravel helpers as in [this thread](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/override-functions-in-supporthelpersphp).

How can I achieve the same in the 5.5 release? I tried a `require` at the top of the `bootstrap/app.php` file with no luck.

Comment: I would define my function in a class and bind that class with service container. and call specific method from `AppServiceProvider` using `boot` method. ro simply put your code inside boot method.

Answer (score 2):

There is a package that can help https://github.com/funkjedi/composer-include-files

Comment: That gets me the `cannot redeclare` error. How did you make it work?

Comment: Updated the answer